# create html design for java website

Tags: java, php, jsp, jsf

guys.

i have few questions about how to design website with JSP(Java).

1- first of all , can we use simple html file as template or must use JSP tags to create it?

2-is it necessary to use JSF or we can do JSP alone?

3-Which have better performance , PHP or JSP?

thanks

Comment: If you want to do a website you have to see if there is a server host in Java in your country too. For exemple here in France we don't have host Java so we use PHP or our server to put a website online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1- first of all , can we use simple html file as template or must use JSP tags to create it?

You can. Although some applications like IBM portal supports HTML themes but you definitely can use simple HTML. You will need the JSP tags special mojo for binding variables, applying conditions (or any logic). Using JSP features making things very easy for you.

Since you tagged question with PHP, I would say using JSP tags like using PHP inside HTML view.

> 2-is it necessary to use JSF or we can do JSP alone?

It's not necessary, I've seen large enterprise web apps using JSP alone but JSF makes things even easier and less ugly and it totally not depending on JSP.

> 3-Which have better performance , PHP or JSP?

This might be opinion based but remember that JSP is java technology and you would compare working with PHP view (which is PHP with whatever front end tech) and Java with front its front end technology (JSP). The way you code your apps, design patterns, handling many other things would effect the answer here.

Note that JSF is a framework on its own and you might use it to make powerful applications comparing to ... say Laravel in PHP. And even more for enterprise apps. But again, it's opinion based.

Answer (score -1):

1. Basically yes you can start with a simple HTML file and build in JSP-Tags like this:

```html
<html>
<head><title>Hello World</title></head>
<body>
    <%
    String message = "Hello World!";
    %>
    <h2><%= message %></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Of course you can do JSP alone. For simple applications this is sufficient. But if you want a nice UI you might want to use a framework like JSF or GWT or Vaadin... there so many possibilities...
3. That depends on what kind of application you want to create. You will need to provide more details...

Edit: As Alan said, Scriptlets are not good practise. And although I think that for a simple example they should be sufficient, here is an example with JSTL core taglib:

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${persons}" var="person">
        <div>${person.forename}</div>
        <div>${person.lastname}</div>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

You can easily see that this is more elegant and should be prefered.

Comment: Using scriptlets in JSP pages has been deprecated for about 15 years.